# drawing a string on the screen C#

Tags: c#, winforms, gdi+

I would like to simply draw a string (if possible in a specific font and size) on the screen (at a specific location). I am within a C# windows forms application. Unfortunately, I could not found any hint on how to do this in the web.

Please help!

Christian

Comment: you want to draw or display any text?

Comment: Do you want to draw anywhere on the screen, or somewhere within your form?

Comment: @Hans - I think he means he couldn't **find how to do it** on the web (i.e. googling didn't help..). But I agree the word "draw" is ambiguous.

Comment: Well yeah sorry for being unprecise. I want to draw the string anywhere on the screen, not within the form

Comment: You can (and should) edit your question to include this information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To draw a string outside of your window, you'll have to CREATE a new window, set it's mask to some color (say magenta) and then draw text onto it - you can use simple label here.

Set your window border style to None, and there you go.

In other words, there is no way of displaying 'free text' without window attached.

For masking color, use 'transparency color' or similar property (I will look up into it later - have no VS at hand)

Comment: I see. Well that sounds like a workaround, but it will be sufficient. Thank you very much!

Comment: Ok, so I recommend this answer as well. I did submit another below but as I noted in that one, I don't think people should draw outside the boarders of their own application.

Answer (score 3):

doing what you are asking for is not really recommended, see e.g. [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20160204044707/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/greg_schechter/archive/2006/05/02/588934.aspx)

If you really want to do something like this; here is a creepy way to do it:

```
    [DllImport("User32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr GetDC(IntPtr hwnd);

    [DllImport("User32.dll")]
    public static extern void ReleaseDC(IntPtr dc);

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        IntPtr desktopDC = GetDC(IntPtr.Zero);

        Graphics g = Graphics.FromHdc(desktopDC);

        g.DrawString("Test", new Font(FontFamily.GenericSerif, 12), Brushes.Blue, 300, 300);
        g.Dispose();

        ReleaseDC(desktopDC);
    }
```

**Please note that I DON'T recommend anyone doing this as I don't think applications should be doing stuff like this. If you want to draw something you should do it on your own form/controls.**

Comment: I know this is super old, but this was useful to me ... only problem is if I call this many times (same text, same location) the text gets really bold, as if the location is slightly off each time. Any ideas as to why?

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI/PAINT_BRUSH.aspx) out.

Or may be you are looking for [DrawString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/76c5db29.aspx) method

Hope this will help

Comment: Thanks, maybe it's worth doing it this way. Thank you!